# Why setDoc(doc(db, colref, id), {...}) not creat new document in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have looked up [Firestore document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9) and see this method to create new document with customized ID

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document in collection "cities"
await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
});
```

However, when I implement as follow, it returns **undefined : doc is not defined**

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, txtEmail.value, txtPassword.value).then((userCredential) => {
        setDoc(doc(db, 'users', userCredential.user.uid), {
              email: txtEmail.value,
              name: "nickname",
              password: txtPassword.value,
              on_line: false,
              creat_time: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
        }).then((docref) => {
              txtEmail.value = "";
              txtPassword.value = "";
              create_alert("success", userCredential.user + " sign up success");
        });
})
```

complete file :

```
import { db, auth } from "./config";
import {collection, getDoc, addDoc, updateDoc, setDoc, Timestamp} from "firebase/firestore";
import {getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth";

    new_account = () => {
        var txtEmail = document.getElementById('inputEmail');
        var txtPassword = document.getElementById('inputPassword');
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, txtEmail.value, txtPassword.value).then((userCredential) => {
            console.log("User: " + txtEmail.value + " has succesfully sign up");
            setDoc(doc(db, 'users', userCredential.user.uid), {
                email: txtEmail.value,
                name: "nickname",
                password: txtPassword.value,
                on_line: false,
                creat_time: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
            }).then((docref) => {
                txtEmail.value = "";
                txtPassword.value = "";
                create_alert("success", userCredential.user + " sign up success");
            });
```

Above is most of my file

Comment: Can you share the complete file so we can see all the imports as well?

Comment: You don't have `import { doc } from "firebase/firestore"; ` in your code... try importing that along with other functions like `setDoc`

Comment: Did not notice that, thankyou so much, my project due in two hours

Answer (score 0):

As @Dharmaraj mentioned the file is missing the doc import: `import { doc } from "firebase/firestore";`